# Callback for Omniauth-Trello (RoR) - can't sign in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, devise, omniauth

I am using RoR 5.2, devise and omniauth-trello gem.
I can't sign in with Trello. 
I need to create ability to sign in without existing user with returned provider and uid: it should create user if it doesn't exist.

I have already added in **config/routes.rb:**

```
devise_for :users, controllers: { omniauth_callbacks: 'omniauth_callbacks' }
```

**config/initializers/devise.rb:**

```
config.omniauth :trello, "#{Rails.application.credentials.trello[:key]}", "#{Rails.application.credentials.trello[:secret]}"
```

**config/initializers/omniauth.rb**

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
      provider :trello, Rails.application.credentials.trello[:key], Rails.application.credentials.trello[:secret],
               app_name: "Trello-Rooney", scope: 'read,write,account', expiration: 'never'
end
```

**app/controllers/omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb**

```
class OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController

      def trello
        @user = User.from_omniauth(request.env['omniauth.auth'])

        if @user.persisted?
          sign_in_and_redirect @user, event: :authentication
          set_flash_message(:notice, :success, kind: 'Trello') if is_navigational_format?
        end
      end

end
```

**app/models/user.rb**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :trackable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable, :omniauthable, omniauth_providers: %i[trello]


  def self.from_omniauth(auth)
    user = User.where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid.to_s).first
    return user if user

    email = auth.info[:email]

    while email.nil?
      generated_email = "#{SecureRandom.base58(10)}@roonyx.trello"
      if User.where(email: generated_email).blank?
        email = generated_email
      end
    end

    user = User.where(email: email).first

    if user
      user.update(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid)
    else
      password = Devise.friendly_token[0, 12]
      user = User.create!(email: email, password: password, password_confirmation: password, provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid)
    end
    user
  end


end
```

But when I am trying to sign in with Trello, I see this in console. Looks like it doesn't cause my callback. Can anyone help? Thank you in advance.

```
E, [2019-05-13T14:10:29.647241 #19958] ERROR -- omniauth: (trello) Authentication failure! service_unavailable: Net::HTTPFatalError, 500 "Internal Server Error"
[2019-05-13 14:10:29] (pida=19958)   INFO -- : Processing by OmniauthCallbacksController#failure as HTML
[2019-05-13 14:10:29] (pida=19958)   INFO -- :   Parameters: {"oauth_token"=>"47215df2b25b4fc089953da32acf0730", "oauth_verifier"=>"8a0b310f2afe98d0aebbd2073efc5b54"}
[2019-05-13 14:10:29] (pida=19958)   INFO -- : Redirected to http://localhost:3000/users/sign_in
[2019-05-13 14:10:29] (pida=19958)   INFO -- : Completed 302 Found in 1ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is right there in your log:
`Authentication failure! service_unavailable: Net::HTTPFatalError, 500 "Internal Server Error"`

Your callback isn't being hit because you've inserted the `OmniAuth::Builder` middleware. You could try removing that and inspecting the `params` that are sent along with the callback.

Once you're removed the middleware you can drop a `byebug` or a `binding.pry` at the top of your callback action. Once you're in the debugger check the value of `request.env['omniauth.auth']`. That should give you some insight as to what the problem is. Hard to say more without knowing more about the environment.

Comment: You are right. After deleting omniauth.rb it works fine as I needed.
This lines of code I took from https://github.com/joshrowley/omniauth-trello.
Thank you!